# I need to add condition or function to change picture after get a new data from database

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

After it receive new data from database i want to use val["id"] make condition to change picture. The fist script is script for get new data from database, the second is an example of condition that i want to do it but it not success.

```js
function getDataFromDb() {
    $.ajax({
        //SELECT * FROM my_db WHERE 1 ORDER BY id DESC limit 1 (Get only newest data from database.)
        url: "getData.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: ''
    }).success(function(result) {
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
        if (obj != '') {
          //$("#myTable tbody tr:not(:first-child)").remove();
          $("#myBody").empty();
          $.each(obj, function(key, val) {
            var tr = "<tr>";
            tr = tr + "<td>" + val["id"] + "</td>";
            tr = tr + "<td>" + val["first_name"] + "</td>";
            tr = tr + "<td>" + val["last_name"] + "</td>";
            tr = tr + "<td>" + val["age"] + "</td>";
            tr = tr + "<td>" + val["hometown"] + "</td>";
            tr = tr + "<td>" + val["job"] + "</td>";
            tr = tr + "</tr>";
            $('#myTable > tbody:last').append(tr);
          });
        }

    });
}
  //get new data from database every 10 second

setInterval(getDataFromDb, 10000); // 1000 = 1 second
```

```
ex. if(val["id"] > 10){
         //Change picture to 1.jpg
        } elseif(val["id"] > 20){
         //Change picture to 2.jpg
        }  else {
         //Change picture to 3.jpg
        };
```

This is an example that i want to get it but i don't know all of syntax to done it

//Thank you

Comment: you need to explain your question!

Comment: your question is not much clear....please explain it little bit more

Comment: I have improved it . If there are another information unclear you can tell me, i will explain it. THANK YOU ALL

Comment: Instead of $('#myTable > tbody:last').append(tr); just use html $('#myTable > tbody:last').html(tr);

Comment: I am new to use ajax. Can you give me for more information about where can i use "src" of each picture. @Neeraj Kumar

Comment: Write a new function changeImage(); in javascript and pass parameter val["id"]; in this function you write a code to change image acc. to id

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your ajax call is missing the `id` value...

```
$.ajax({
        //SELECT * FROM my_db WHERE 1 ORDER BY id DESC limit 1 (Get only newest data from database.)
        url: "getData.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {id: 'YOUR-ID-GOES-HERE'}
    }
    .....
```

Comment: It just got a newest id from "getData.php". Can you help me to add new condition or function to change picture after get new "id" from database or improve above source code?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly. It seems like your code already reads the `val["id"]`

Comment: My script above just get data from database,but I want to create or add new condition or function to use `val["id"]` to define to change picture. I didn't know how to create or some syntax to do it.